# Laravel queue worker: Ideal setup on managed hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I would like to improve my queue worker setup on Laravel 10 on a managed server (so no root access, but SSH access. Hetzner Managed Server)

I can't use supervisor so over the time I came up with the following setup which is working for most cases very well but has here and there some timeouts which I can't explain to myself since it's not happening all the time.

My schedule method in app/Console/Kernel.php looks like this for the last years:

```
    $schedule->call(function() use ($phpShellCmd) {
        shell_exec("php ".base_path()."/artisan queue:restart");
        file_put_contents(storage_path()."/logs/scheduler.log", "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] queue:restart executed.\n", FILE_APPEND);
    })->everyMinute();

    for($i = 0; $i < $num_of_workers; $i++) {
        $schedule->call(function() use ($i, $laravelbasedir) {
            $cmd = "php ".base_path()."/artisan queue:work --queue=MainQueue,OrderQueue --timeout=60 >> ".storage_path()."/logs/queueworker.log 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &";
            file_put_contents(storage_path()."/logs/scheduler.log", "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] execute queue:work #".($i+1).":".$cmd."\n", FILE_APPEND);
            shell_exec($cmd);
        })->everyMinute()->runInBackground();
    }
```

Idea behind it is, that the queue is gracefully "restarted" every minute and then there are $num_of_workers queue workers started every minute (to not have the need to restart the queue after each code update and also to make sure that the queue worker is "always" running even when it crashes since there is no supervisor running on that server). Also there is a timeout of 60s so that we don't have super many workers running in the end if no worker crashes. So there are always only running approx. $nun_of_workers.

Despite the 60s timeout, my jobs can usually run longer, which is nice and needed. Nevertheless it seems that sometimes they run into timeouts, ending with "...Job has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out." instead of the last occurred exception.

I believe that my solution is not the ideal way to deal with that but besides some smaller problems it has worked well for me so far.

Now I would like to learn a better way of constantly running queue workers on a managed server without root access an no supervisor running and learn about the pros and cons of a possible new implementation.

Answer (score 0):

On my managed servers I use cron directly to (re)start any queues. The cron job is set up in such a way that it's not allowed to launch again if the previous one is still running. When using `artisan queue:work` to launch your queues, this actually results in long-running workers because in normal operations `queue:work` keeps running and hence the cron command will just exit in 99% of the time.

I'm using `flock` with great success, but it depends of course whether it's available on your system (`lockrun` and `lckdo` are alternatives).

```
* * * * * $(which flock) --nonblock path/to/queue.lockfile --command "php path/to/artisan queue:work"
```

- `--nonblock` makes the about-to-be-started command be skipped if still running a previous instance
- `path/to/queue.lockfile` is a file `flock` can read/write to in order to check for already running commands
- `--command "...."` the command to be executed if `flock` detects it's allowed to proceed.

If you need multiple workers, configure a cron job for each worker with a dedicated lockfile.

Things to keep in mind with this setup:

- Queues should always be started by cron, not by any deployment script (because otherwise `flock` won't be able to detect it)
- If a queue exits (either by `queue:restart`, by failure, ...) you'll need to await the next cron round before it gets restarted.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and sorry for getting back to you so late. I just didn't notice the notification email. 
This is definitely an approach I could also test. But I still think it's pretty similar to my current approach just that I have one cron every minute to execute the scheduler and from there the queue workers will be started. Are there any advantages when starting the workers directly via cron? My advantage right now is that I have that configuration in my version control. Also do you have any idea about the timeout problem I mentioned in my 3rd paragraph from the bottom?